# Table filters in Vuejs

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm building a small application in `vuejs` where I'm having a filter something like this:

```
tableFilter: function () {
    const searchTerm = this.search.toLowerCase();
    const searchByType = this.search_by_tag.toLowerCase();
    if(this.contactStore.contactList)
    {
        return this.contactStore.contactList.data.filter((item) =>
            (item.first_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
                || (item.last_name !==null && item.last_name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                || (item.company.name !==null && item.company.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                || item.email.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)
                || (item.address !== null && item.address.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                || (item.city !== null && item.city.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm))
                || (item.mobile !==null && item.mobile.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm)))
        && ((item.profile !==null && item.profile.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType))
            || (item.company.type !== null && item.company.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType))
            || (item.company.sub_type !== null && item.company.sub_type.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType))));
    }
},
```

In this I've a property called `item.company` which can be null, so while implementing

```
(item.company.type !== null && item.company.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType))
```

it is throwing error:

> Error in render function: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null"

I'm looking for a solution where I can have if-else to find out whether the item is having company or not, if property is available then it can do the filters respectively.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to fix the error:

```
|| (item.company && item.company.type !== null && item.company.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType))
```

But if you want to not filter by company if it is null:

```
|| (item.company ? && item.company.type !== null && item.company.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType) : true)
```

Comment: I thought it can be something like this: `(item.company !== null && item.company.type !== null && item.company.type.toLowerCase().includes(searchByType))`

Comment: null is falsy in javascript so you can just do (item.company && ...)

Comment: Thanks, it helped.. :)